# Magento 2 : How to add virtual domain in localhost?

Tags: magento2

I have a magento2 folder on my localhost

```
var/www/html/magento2
```

***I want to open a website like magento2.com instead of localhost/magento2.***

How to achieve this.

i have read many tutorials but there are lots of issues.

Sometime Magento2.com opens the apache webpage, some times CSS issue on the front end.

please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1:  copy default config file.

Run from command line:: `sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/magento2.com.conf`

& you can open magento2.com.conf file using nano command.

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/magento2.com.conf
```

Step 2: add below code on new file magento2.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin magento2@test.com
    ServerName magento2.com
    ServerAlias www.magento2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/magento2
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <Directory /var/www/html/magento2>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Step 3: Enable virtual host configuration files

From command line: `sudo a2ensite magento2.com.conf`

Step 4: start apache service

From command line:  `sudo service apache2 restart`

Step 5: add host entry

From command line: `sudo nano /etc/hosts`

add below line in hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 magento2.com
```

Step 6:

upade below url on value column of core_config_data.

```
http://magento2.com/
```

Step 7: go to `var/www/html/magento2` & run below commands,

```
1. sudo chmod -R 0777 var pub generated
2. sudo php bin/magento c:f
```